# How can I find the maximum value in this queue?

Tags: c++11, queue

I want to find maximum value in this queue, How can I solve this?

```
queue<pair<int , int> > q;
 for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){ 
  int p; 
  cin >> p; 
  q.push(make_pair(p, i)); 
 }
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: `queue<pair<int , int> > q;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
 int p;
 cin >> p;
 q.push(make_pair(p, i));
    }`


Want to find max value in that code...

Comment: define a var max to be equal to the first element. pop or dequeue all elements one by one from the queue and each time compare with the max variable you have defined if the current element is greater than the max then make max = current at the end you have the max element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your issue correctly if not please leave a comment, please check this code and I hope that it will do whatever you need.

```
queue<pair<int , int> > q; 
int max=-1;//you can use INT_MIN in case you're accepting negative numbers too 

for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{ 
int p;
 cin >> p; 
//if you need to be based ONLY on user input 
if(p > max) max = p;
//if you need to be based on BOTH user input and current i
//if(p+i > max) max = p+I;
//if you need to be based on ONLY current i
//if(i > max) max = i;
q.push(make_pair(p, i)); 

}
```